# Pandas read_csv is there a way to convert sqlachemy data types to pandas dtypes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to read in a csv that I will eventually push to a database. I have a predetermined data model that the data will end up as. Also the csv does not have a header.

If I define a model for example:

```
class SamFoo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    duns = Column(Text)
    duns_plus_four = Column(Text)
    cage_code = Column(Text)
    dodaac = Column(Text)
    sam_extract_code = Column(Text)
    purpose_of_registration = Column(Text)
    initial_registration_date = Column(DateTime)
    ...
```

If I try to `read_csv`,

```
sam_name_type_dict = {c.name: c.type for c in SamFoo.__table__.c}
sam_name_type_dict.pop('id', None) # id isn't in csv data.
raw_data = pd.read_csv(
        data,
        sep='|',
        skiprows=1,
        header=None,
        names=list(sam_name_type_dict.keys()),
        dtype=sam_name_type_dict,
    )
```

I am getting a `TypeError: data type not understood`, so my question is, is there a way to map sqlachemy data types to pandas dtypes?

Comment: How about creating own mapper like when c.type=='TEXT' treat is as 'str' ? I know it sounds silly but should work.

Comment: @user2695448 hey, that is exactly what I ended up doing. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/8hpkm2/is_there_a_way_to_map_pandas_dtypes_to_sqlachemy/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime, Integer, Boolean, Text
import numpy as np
types_map = {
    Text: object,
    DateTime: np.datetime64,
    Integer: np.float64, # NA integer gotcha https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na
    Boolean: bool,
}

# had to split dates and regular dtypes into separate dicts
sam_sql_types = {c.name: c.type for c in SamFoo.__table__.c}
sam_sql_types.pop('id', None) # no id in csv
sam_dtypes = {k: types_map[type(v)] for k, v in sam_sql_types.items()}
sam_dates = {k: v for k, v in sam_dtypes.items() if v == np.datetime64}
sam_dtypes_non_dates = {k: v for k, v in sam_dtypes.items() if v != np.datetime64}

raw_data = pd.read_csv(
    data,
    sep='|',
    skiprows=1,
    header=None,
    names=list(sam_sql_types.keys()),
    dtype=sam_dtypes_non_dates,
    parse_dates=list(sam_dates.keys())
)
```